# Why do I get NA values after filtering a dataset and running a regression based on that set?

Tags: filtering, linear-regression, resultset

I am using the gpa1 dataset in R and am trying to filter out all instances where a student has worked less than or equal to 19 hours and does not volunteer or participate in any clubs. I can run the filter and save the data fine, and get the results I want (job19=1, clubs=0, and voluntr=0, but when I try to run a regression based on the new dataset the job19 values just come up as "NA"

This is the code that I used:

PTjob19 <- filter(gpa1, job19 == 1, voluntr == 0, clubs == 0)

View(PTjob19)

olsreg9 <- lm(colGPA~job19 + age + male + hsGPA + ACT + siblings + skipped + fathcoll + mothcoll, data=PTjob19)

I expected that job19 would have some kind of value be it negative or positive, but the values were just listed as "NA." Cam someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out.  The reason I was getting an "NA" value was that I wasn't giving R anything to compare.  I was trying to run a regression where people only worked less than 20 jobs, which of course R couldn't give me stats on.